# Openflow: Should metadata be sent to the controller?

Tags: openflow, opendaylight

I am designing an OpenDaylight / OpenFlow application where I put in a Flow rule that sends the packet to the controller on match. The match gets presented to my application as a packetIn notification. I am writing metadata on match in my flow rule before sending to controller. Will the metadata be presented to my ODL controller PacketIn dispatcher?

Answer (score 0):

For the benefit of others:

I determined that in opendaylight the metadata match is not seen in the notification that the packet in listener sees.
However, I noted that the flow cookie IS passed to the listener so if you want to know what rule matched, you have to encode that information in the flow cookie.